# What data structure can be used to store the windows directory structure in cpp?

Tags: c++, windows, directory

I have to develop a data structure for storing windows directory info and the folder time related properties so that when i create the folder at the time of restores i can assign the right time to each folder starting from the child node to the parent node .

Comment: The best way I know to manage directories in C++ is using boost::filesystem. I'm not sure it can do directly what you want, but you should check it.

Comment: Are you wanting something like the [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and [`GetFileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? (they say 'file' but it's also what you use to get directory info) .. you could use those to loop through a directory and get it's files/folders and their information .. or are you wanting something like a file system watcher type ala the [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Restore _only_ the time? That's almost certainly not enough. You need to restore all metadata, including the ACL. (Besides, _which_ time did you mean anyway? Creation, modification, or access?)

Comment: The folders are restored properly with acls but it is just the create and modified time that i want to change . I want to restore from the child to the parent node because if i change the parent node times first and then the child node time then the parent node modified time will be the child not modification time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tree directory structure with node having properties name, type and number of child ,time and other fields based on the requirements to implement the filesystem.